# Test Failover failing in Azure ASR

Tags: azure, migration, failover, azure-site-recovery

After replication of source machines, when I tried to 'Test Failover' the VM, got error in the process. Earlier the same server got 'Test Failover-ed' successfully. The error codes are 28027, 150284, 539. The machine has more than 1 NIC, when secondary NICs are set to be not created, the 'Test Failover' works. Is the issue because of some changes in local network or it is because Microsoft has made some changes?

Let me know if more details related to error is required.

Comment: @4c74356b41 can you help please ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved on its own when tried next day. It seems the issue was on Azure side.